# Generating a alphanumeric values in series

Tags: javascript

I would like to generate a alphanumeric series in the fashion - AA0AAA00

The next would be AA0AAA01, AA0AAA02 ... AA0AAA99, AA0AAB00, AA0AAB01....AA0AAZ99, AA0ABA00 upto ZZ9ZZZ99

I have tried with

```
var start = "AA0AAA00"
var current = start
while (start != "ZZ9ZZZ99")
{
    current = current + 1
    console.log(current)
}
```

Comment: AB0AAA00 comes after AA9ZZZ99. My mistake Sorry.

Comment: Specifying a start and end would be even better so I can capture the series between the two limits

Comment: While "adding" to string values this way basically works in JavaScript, you can not expect this to also take your specific requirements of having different "sets" of possible characters in different positions, into account at the same time. You will need to develop your own, a bit more sophisticated solution yourself here.

Comment: I would recommend that you start by treating this a bit more like "regular" math. How adding one to a given number works (on the really "low level"), you should already be familiar with: You check if the last digit is already a 9 first, if not, you simply add the 1 to that and are done, if not it becomes a 0, and you need to play "carry the one" with the next position. This here is little different, only that you have to take into account that you have different sets of "digits" with different ranges & "overflow points."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive generator solution. First it translates the pattern to ranges of "digits" for each position, and then the recursion iterates each character in the range for the first position and leaves the rest to the recursion.

For the example run I just took the pattern "A0" so to limit the size of the output here:

```js
function* gen(start) {
    let ranges = Array.from(start, ch =>
        ch == "0" ? "0123456789" : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    );
    
    function* recur(range, ...rest) {
        if (!rest.length) return yield* range;
        for (let ch of range) {
            for (let out of recur(...rest)) {
                yield ch + out;
            }
        }
    }
    
    yield* recur(...ranges);
}

console.log([...gen("A0")]);
```

Comment: Stylistically I don't like the space before the `*`.  Because [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) is a different thing from `function` and [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) is a different thing from `yield`.

Comment: Alright, Wyck -- updated to use that compact style.